# how to get first JSONs elements using python

Tags: json, python-3.x

The public API respond me with JSON which has the next format

```
{"ABCD-EFG":
    {"param1":"0.1234",
     "param2":"0.123456",
     "param3":"0.12334254"},
 "HIG-KLMN":
    {"param1":"0.3456",
     "param2":"0.05710" 
     "param3":"0.004903"
   ... }
```

How can i get the List of the names (in this examle ABCD-EFG, HIG-KLMN) using Python3 ?

They can make changes in it every API get request sending

If it was like  'name' : 'ABCD-EFG', it would be easy. But it's not like that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a few ways, here's one:

```
x = {
  "ABCD-EFG": {
    "param1":"0.1234",
    "param2":"0.123456",
    "param3":"0.12334254"
  },
  "HIG-KLMN": {
    "param1":"0.3456",
    "param2":"0.05710",
    "param3":"0.004903"
  }
}

y = list(x.keys())
print(y)

for key in x.keys():
    print(key)
```

gives:

```
['ABCD-EFG', 'HIG-KLMN']
ABCD-EFG
HIG-KLMN
```

Comment: Downvotes should be be accompanied by a comment explaining why and what for.